# Power supply with 10 VDC and 2mA

Tags: power-supply, batteries, dc

I have device need 10 V DC and 2 mA, can I use DC battery? For example, two batteries with 5 V DC and 1000 mAh?

Comment: How critical is that voltage?

Comment: its from 10-16 Vdc

Comment: If the lower 10V limit is critical, then 5V batteries probably won't satisfy your requirement because their voltage will droop a little when they're loaded. You could use a pair of 6V batteries, though, to get 12V... or you could use a single 12V battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your spec. 10~16V typically mean you can use 12V . Since if you use 10 V as George Herold suggested, after a while when due to load variation , the voltage may drop below 10 V resulting mal-operation. So in my opinion u can use any standard 12V battery , since current consumption solely depens on your equipment load.
Greetings and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, put the batteries in series.  With 2mA current draw they should last for 500 hours of continuous use.